# Is possible to export data using DWLoader?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

Is it possible to export data from a table to flat file using DWLoader?
If so please help me with a sample command line on how it's done.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DWLoader is just for loading data.  If you are looking for a command line utility to export table data, you should probably use `bcp`

[`bcp` Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

[Questions Tagged with BCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bcp)